Double XLOOKUP in Excel
I have an Excel-workbook containing two sheets:

One sheet contains the names of students with their evaluation


And a second sheet containing the "mappings" between the criteria and the possible values with their corresponding score



So basically, I need to lookup the name of the criteria in the Students-sheet to "return" the columns of the criteria. Within these colums, I need to look for the value and return the corresponding score.
Based on my 'Students' sheet, how can I calculate the total score for each student?
Thank you very much!

Easiest is using named ranges:
On 'Scores'

Select A2 through B4, name it Crit1
Select C2 through D4, name it Crit2
Select E2 through F4, name it Crit3

On 'Students' apply this formula on the right most column:
=XLOOKUP(C2, CHOOSECOLS(Crit1,1), CHOOSECOLS(Crit1,2)) + XLOOKUP(D2, CHOOSECOLS(Crit2,1), CHOOSECOLS(Crit2,2)) + XLOOKUP(E2, CHOOSECOLS(Crit3,1), CHOOSECOLS(Crit3,2))

Alternativly, you can do it without the named ranges:
=XLOOKUP(Students!C2, Scores!$A$2:$A$4, Scores!$B$2:$B$4) + XLOOKUP(Students!D2, Scores!$C$2:$C$4, Scores!$D$2:$D$4) + XLOOKUP(Students!E2, Scores!$E$2:$E$4, Scores!$F$2:$F$4) 

Drag down for all students.

EDIT: Since there's about 18 criteria, you might want to consider a slight change to your 'Scores' sheet, make it like such:

Then try this formula:
=SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(Scores!$A$2:$S$4,XMATCH(Students!C2:T2,Scores!$A$2:$A$4),TRIM(RIGHT(Students!$C$1:$T$1,2))+1),0))

Adjust range accordinly.

Thank you very much for your reply! Is it possible to make the repeating XLOOKUP's variable, so I don't have to repeat this?

I meant if there are a lot more criteria. I'm sorry for the confusion

@Sam how many are we talking? Or is it variable through time?

about 18 criteria

@Sam I added a simple solution, if you have the possibility to change your scores sheet a bit, and you're using the same criteria.

You can also use LAMBDA function:
=REDUCE(0, SEQUENCE(3), 
LAMBDA(a,b, a+ XLOOKUP(INDEX($C$2:$E$3,,b), 
INDEX(Scores!$A$2:$F$4,,2*b-1), INDEX(Scores!$A$2:$F$4,,2*b))))

This formula is easy to scale up. 3 means the number of criteria, the range C2:E3 represents student ratings, Scores!A2:F4 represents the whole "mapping".

Here is my proposal, using one single dynamic array formula, which will spill for the whole data in sheet Students:


• Formula used in cell F2
=BYROW(C2:E3,LAMBDA(α,LET(ε,Scores!A2:F4,δ,LAMBDA(φ,
  CHOOSECOLS(ε,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(ε)/2)*2-φ)),SUM(IFERROR((α=δ(1))*δ(0),0)))))


You will need to increase the range as per your suit.

